# Spawning bash from python and printing message

Tags: python, bash

I would like to know if there is a way to spawn a login shell and display a message to the user. The rules:

- the user has his own ~/.bashrc and we do not want to overwrite it
- avoid using pipe to the subprocess

What I am doing atm:

```
def do_bash(tokens, state):
    """
    Drop into system shell or execute shell commands. Examples:

    - bash
    - bash -c "ls ~/.* | grep shell"
    """
    cmd = ["bash", "-l"]
    if len(tokens):
        cmd.extend(tokens)
    subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I have tried combining `-l` with `-c echo "<message>"` but this only displays the message in a new shell and then returns.

UDPATE: To simplify this - I want to execute `subprocess.call(["bash", "-l", "<magic I am not sure of>"])` and from the user's perspective:

```
$ python ./mycode.py
I0000 03:16:11 [mycode] Various logging messages until subprocess is called

  You have dropped into a temporary shell but you are still
  within "mycode.py" program. You can use "exit" to continue
  running the script. This shell allows to you to do foo and bar.

bash$
```

Comment: You should be more specific what you want from .bashrc and in which context this is to be run (as a different user?). I also do not understand the reference to piping. It would probably be easiest if you give a little minimal running program and tell us what you expect as an output.

Comment: @JonasEberle: I give you an example of the behavior I need. However, I do not want to modify `.bashrc` - I could just append an "echo " from python into that file and then do `bash -l` but I dont want to touch such files. Also, I could do `subprocess.call/Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)` and then use `communicate` but I also try to avoid this. The question is if there is a bash flag to execute a command on login and keep the shell open afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `bash` will give you the interactive shell with the loaded environment from `/etc/bashrc` + `~/.bashrc`.

If you want a login shell, `bash -l` is correct.

For getting your pretext shown (with bash), you need a second invocation of bash because it can be either run to execute given commands or as an interactive shell. If you do not really need the pretext be parsed by bash, I suggest to output the pretext with python instead.

Comment: Sh1t man!! Why I didn't think of that, no need to echo it!! Let me give it a try (over engineering sometimes maybe...)

Comment: Seems like a stupid question now, but I am leaving it up to remember to not post before my second coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call bash with `-l` then `~/.bashrc` is not executed. Instead, because you ask for a login shell, `~/.bash_profile` is executed (if it exists).

I have therefore this in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

What you probably want is to call bash without `-l`.